# Receiving Unwanted Password Reset

Tags: email, apple-id

A while back I had added a secondary email address to Apple ID which had not belonged to me. A few years later I keep receiving messages of activity of that account (reset the password, change of details, etc.).

My Apple ID account is not associated with that account, I just receive emails from that account with information, because *I added my mail as secondary mail.*

I do not want to receive these emails. I cannot reach this person.

Comment: I don't know how you get an email of another person without having access to their account (email password). My advise would be to contact the email service provider directly and inform them of this issue. (So if you are getting email from someone@gmail.com or someone@hotmail.com, contact Gmail or Hotmail and tell them that you are receiving the emails of this particular email ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do know this person but did not want to contact. Apple Support could not intervene either as it is prohibited for them to change user's data.

Albeit, I have contacted that person and we have solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

One would imagine that the email 'master' set up for that ID would still be in use, as the owner makes periodic changes.
Did you try writing to that email? Only the owner of the ID can change any aspect of it, including the recovery email address.

Alternatively, you may end up having to use mail rules to just throw them out.

Comment: If OP isn't on a Mac or otherwise cannot use Mail rules, most mail providers will quickly "learn" that you don't want to see something if you move those types of emails to the spam folder. The downside would be that other Apple emails might be automatically moved to the spam folder as well.

Comment: I do know this person but did not want to contact. Apple Support could not intervene either as it is prohibited for them to change user's data.

Comment: Albeit, I have contacted that person and we have solved that issue.

Comment: @SagittariusA Please post this as an Answer. Comments are not indexed, but if posted as an Answer, it will be indexed and the information about how you solved the problem will be available to others.